# Comparing text within 2 columns in different workbooks

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to compare all the cells in two columns, each column in different workbooks.
The cells contain text and numbers, and if the two cells (each in different workbooks) are different, I want one of the cells to be highlighted/colored/filled.

**Task:**

1.1 - Cell1 = Hi

1.1 - Cell2 = Hi

So no highlight need here, both values are equal

1.2 - Cell1 = Hello

1.2 - Cell2 = Hellod

Highlight is needed here, both values are not equal to one another

**NOTE: Both Cell1 and Cell2 are in different workbooks**

**Here is the code I have so far:**

```
Sub DescriptionDiscrepency()
```

- Set the location of file to an object
- Target Path is redundant in my code but might be useful for you guys

  ```
  Target_Path = "C:\Users\Example.xlsm"


  Set Target_Workbook = Workbooks("Example.xlsm")
  Target_Workbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Unprotect Password:="****"
  Set Source_Workbook = Workbooks("Example2.xlsm")
  Source_Workbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Unprotect Password:="*****"
  ```

  - Read Data from Target File to see if source file matches up

    ```
    Target_Data = Target_Workbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 6).CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
    Source_Data = Source_Workbook.Sheets("Sheet1`").Cells(5, 2).CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
    ```
  - Highlight if CAT description is not same in our status tracker
  - **This part is not working**

    ```
    For i = 1 To lastRow
    For j = 1 To lastRow
        If Source_Data.Cells(j, 1).Value <> "" Then  
            If StrComp(Source_Data.Cells(j, 2).Value, 
                Target_Data.Cells(i, 6).Value, CompareMethod.Text) = 0 Then

                Source_Data.Cells(j, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = RGB(255, 255, 255) 
                Source_Data.Cells(j, 2).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) 

            Else
                Source_Data.Cells(j, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = RGB(0, 0, 0) 
                Source_Data.Cells(j, 2).Font.Color = RGB(255, 199, 206) 
            End If
        End If
    Next j
    Next I
    End Sub
    ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing a few things. Namely range objects (actual cells in Excel) and row counts (simple numbers).

Try it like this:

```
Set Target_Data = Target_Workbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 6).CurrentRegion
Set Source_Data = Source_Workbook.Sheets("Sheet1`").Cells(5, 2).CurrentRegion

For i = 1 To Target_Data.Rows.Count
For j = 1 To Source_Data.Rows.Count
  If Source_Data.Cells(j, 1).Value <> "" Then  
    If StrComp(Source_Data.Cells(j, 2).Value, Target_Data.Cells(i, 6).Value, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then

      Source_Data.Cells(j, 2).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255) 
      Source_Data.Cells(j, 2).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) 

    Else
      Source_Data.Cells(j, 2).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) 
      Source_Data.Cells(j, 2).Font.Color = RGB(255, 199, 206) 
    End If
  End If
Next j
Next I
End Sub
```

Comment: Hmm, it's giving me an error for:        If StrComp(Source_Data.Cells(j, 2).Value, Target_Data.Cells(i, 6).Value, CompareMethod.Text) = 0 Then   , its giving me an object required error

Comment: I fixed it by using: If StrComp(Source_Data.Cells(j, 2).Value, Target_Data.Cells(i, 6).Value, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then   instead of using it with CompareMethod.Text

Comment: Oh, yeah. I was wondering what that Comparemethod.Text was there for, but I guessed you had something in a Class module or something... I'll update my answer. :)